# How do i execute a multi line command through docker compose?

Tags: bash, docker, shell, docker-compose, sh

I want to execute the following command inside my docker container through docker compose

```
cat <<EOT >> /config.toml
[[tls.certificates]]
  certFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.site/fullchain.pem"
  keyFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.site/privkey.pem"
EOT
```

Here's the basic docker compose for this particular container

```
  container:
    image: container-image
    command:
      - --api=true
      - --dashboard=true
```

I want to add that multi line command below those two commands. If it was a single command, i could have simply used

`- sh -c "echo 'single line command'"`
But how do i execute this multi line command in this instance ?

Comment: Those 2 commands that you have in your file are not shell commands. They're parameters for whatever is defined as the entrypoint in the container. I doubt that entrypoint would accept your `sh` command.

Comment: Why not write this command in a shell script, copy that in the container and execute?

Comment: I don't think that can be done as pointed out by @HansKilian the command is accepting parameters too in this case, so shell command most probably won't get accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't run a command like this in a Compose file.

Remember that a container only runs a single command, and then exits.  This makes it hard to use `command:` to create a configuration file, for example, since that will be the only thing the container does.  For this setup, as noted in comments, this is even more complicated because the `command:` is actually a list of arguments to some other command.  You could reverse-engineer what the image does and override its `entrypoint:`, but that gets very complicated very quickly.

Since you're just trying to provide a static config file, you should create it on the host and inject it via a bind mount using Compose `volumes:`.  It looks like you're trying to append content to an existing configuration, so you may need to start by extracting the existing configuration.

```bash
docker create --name tmp container-image
docker cp tmp:/etc/letsencrypt/config.toml ./
docker rm tmp

$EDITOR config.toml  # and add the lines shown, on the host
```

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  container:
    image: container-image
    command:
      - --api=true
      - --dashboard=true
    volumes:                                       # <-- add if not present
      - ./config.toml:/etc/letsencrypt/config.toml # <-- add
```